# Loading UITableView with JSON from AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, afnetworking

I am trying to populate a UITableView with a remote JSON file.  I am able to grab the JSON in the repsonseObject but am having trouble with the TableView. I am storing the JSON in an array.

My request looks like this:

```
- (void)makeJSONRequest
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager GET:@"http://www.tylacock.com/cheats.json" parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             self.jsonFromAFNetworking = [responseObject objectForKey:@"ps3"];
         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

And my cellForRowAtIndexPath method looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *tempDict = [self.jsonFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [tempDict objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

I have checked to make sure the data source is connected to the ViewController. I was actually able to accomplish this with AFNetworking 1.X but since the upgrade and method changes I am at a loss.

Comment: Can I ask what jsonFromAFNetworking is? An NSObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading the data asynchrously, so you've got to call `[self.tableView reloadData]` after setting `jsonFromAFNetworking`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That was the problem